# Multi Authentication Different tables Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel

I have my Auth configuration set to the customer and they log in with a customer number. 
Problem is the staff need to also log on with their staff id.

I would need both:

```
$customer = array(
        'username'=>Input::get('customer_no'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password')
        );
```

and for staff

```
$customer = array(
        'username'=>Input::get('staff_id'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password')
        );
```

They need different models from the tables Customers and Staff

I am using Eloquent can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: The Table have both `staff_id` and `customer_no` or You are sending different variables to point same coloumn name ?

Comment: i need multiple authentication with different tables. Suppose you have table users and table costumers. I need to redirect users and customers to different routes.

Comment: Yes it is possible you shall use if(firsttable){}else(secondtable) and try , If not convey , so that i shall convey you